# Search functionality does not work in C# with LINQ and JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, join, .net-core, collections

In Reservation method, I want to reduce the size of the queryList based on the searchItem parameter depending on whether the element contains a word from searchItem or not. However, no matter what I type, the list doesn't shrink, it always stays the same size. Where am I wrong? If you can help I would appreciate it.

```cs
public async Task<IResponse<ReservationFundSearchResult>> Reservation(string searchTerm, string supplierCode, string customerCode, string kpp = null)
{
    try
    {
        supplierCode ??= string.Empty;
        customerCode ??= string.Empty;
        searchTerm = searchTerm?.Trim().ToLower();

        var queryList = (from reservation in _dbContext.Reservations
            .Where(reservation => searchTerm.IsNullOrEmpty() 
                || reservation.DocumentNumber.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)
                || reservation.DocumentHeaderText.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)
                || (kpp.IsNotNullOrEmpty() && reservation.KPP.ToLower() == kpp.ToLower())
            )
            .Where(reservation => !reservation.IsDeleted 
                && (reservation.CompletionDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue 
                || reservation.CompletionDate > DateTimeOffset.Now)
                && (reservation.Supplier.ToLower() == supplierCode.ToLower() 
                || reservation.Supplier.ToLower() == customerCode.ToLower())
                && (reservation.FinancialCenter.ToLower() == customerCode.ToLower() 
                || reservation.FinancialCenter.ToLower() == supplierCode.ToLower())
            )
            join fund in _dbContext.FundingSources
            on reservation.FundSource equals fund.FundCode into reservations
            from reservationItem in reservations.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new ReservationFundPair()
            {
                Code = reservation.DocumentNumber,
                Description = reservation.DocumentHeaderText,
                FundCode = reservationItem.FundCode,
                FundDescription = reservationItem.Name
            }).Distinct();

        ReservationFundSearchResult result = await TransformToReservationFundSearchResult(queryList);

        return SuccessResponse.Success(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"{nameof(Reservation)} failed");
        return ErrorResponse.Error<ReservationFundSearchResult>(Shared.Common.ErrorCode.UnspecifiedError);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any of those `searchTerm.IsNullOrEmpty() ||` calls. You can append `Where` clauses dynamically, eg `if (someParam!=null){ query=query.Where(...); }`. Nor do you need `ToLower()` if the database uses a case-insensitive collation. In fact, you should avoid modifying field values because that prevents the database from using indexes

Comment: You shouldn't have to JOIN in EF Core either. EF Core is an ORM, not a SQL replacement. The objects should have proper relations and navigation properties, eg `Reservation` should have a `FundSource` or `FundSources` property. It's EF Core's job to generate the JOINs as needed. You could write just `query.Select(reservation=>new ..{ .... ,FundCode=reservation.FundSource.FundCode})`